# I have tried to compile this code unfortunately i usually get error

Tags: solidity

This is the code: `function () external payable {`

The error when compiling:

> ParserError: Expected a state variable declaration. If you intended this as a fallback function or a function to handle plain ether transactions, use the "fallback" keyword or the "receive" keyword instead. --> mytoken.sol:145:32: | 145 | function () external payable { | ^

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, please read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question and come back when you have read through it. Your question lacks a lot of details, please improve on it for faster help with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because you're using syntax from Solidity 0.5 or older in version 0.6 or newer.

In Solidity 0.6, the fallback function was changed, and the new syntax is

```
pragma solidity ^0.6;

contract MyContract {

   fallback() external payable {
      // TODO implement or leave empty
   }

}
```

You can find more info in the docs section [breaking changes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/060-breaking-changes.html#semantic-and-syntactic-changes).